# Making number from elements of list

Tags: python, algorithm, subset-sum

How can i check that can i create a number from elements of list?

For example:
list=[1,1,3,3,3,3,5,10,23,53]

And now we can make 9 from [1,3,5] or [3,3,3]
i tried something like that:

```
list=[1,1,3,3,3,3,5,10,23,53]
tmp=[]
sum=0

for i in range(len(list)):
  tmpChange=9
  tmpChange -= list[i]+sum
  if tmpChange == 0:
      break
  elif tmpChange > 0:
      tmp.append(list[i])
      sum += list[i]
      print(tmpChange)
      print(tmp)
  else:
      tmp.pop(i)
```

Comment: Read online on "subset sum", it is a known and well defined problem.

Comment: Aside from your main question, you are assigning things to built-ins like `list` and `sum`. This is not recommended. Try naming your variables something like `my_list` or `my_sum` instead.

Comment: This is "Knapsack problem", to be exact. No effective solution to this problem is known, so I suggest you just try all subsets. It has exponential complexity though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A naive way to approach this is to find all of the subsets of your original list, which you can do using `itertools.combinations`. Then you can check if the subset sums to your original value, then add them to a `set`.

```
import itertools
l = [1,1,3,3,3,3,5,10,23,53]
total = 9
values = set()
for r in range(1, len(l)):
    for c in itertools.combinations(l, r):
        if sum(c) == total:
            values.add(tuple(c))
```

The result is then

```
>>> values
{(1, 3, 5), (3, 3, 3)}
```

As another example using the following data

```
l = [1,1,3,3,3,3,4,5,9,10,23,53]
```

The result would be

```
>>> values
{(4, 5), (3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 5), (9,)}
```